# eth_account Account.encrypt and Account.decrypt

Tags: python, json, encryption

I'm new to using eth_account in python and I'm trying to understand the use of the Account.encrypt(private_key, password, kdf=None, iterations=None) and Account.decrypt(keyfile_json, password) methods. From the documentation https://eth-account.readthedocs.io/en/stable/eth_account.html.
I have the account private key saved as a string after encrypting using the Account.encrypt(). Then I'm trying to load it back into a dictionary to use the Account.decrypt() because passing the string encrypted key failed, so I tried to load it with json.loads() method before passing it as the keyfile_json to decrypt(). I apologize if I am misunderstanding this whole concept, but here's what I'm doing:

```
from eth_account import Account
import json

Account.enable_unaudited_hdwallet_features()

# create a wallet for the new user and generate a recovery mnemonic
acct_new, mnemonic = Account.create_with_mnemonic(passphrase = formPassword, num_words = 12, language = 'english')

# saving the account key as string after encrypting with Account.encrypt()
strEncryptedKey = str(Account.encrypt(acct_new.key, password = 'password'))
```

The string encrypted key is in the following format when saved and retrieved:

```
{'address': '...', 'crypto': {'cipher': 'aes-128-ctr', 'cipherparams': {'iv': '68ba2c02df490b55fb036de8031a9d41'}, 'ciphertext': '...', 'kdf': 'scrypt', 'kdfparams': {'dklen': 32, 'n': 262144, 'r': 1, 'p': 8, 'salt': 'fb4a642ec779c169ba332d294d549344'}, 'mac': '...'}, 'id': '06f170b4-a493-4798-80f0-0292adead5e7', 'version': 3}
```

When it's reloaded for signing and sending transactions:

```
# For testing purposes I'm reloading the strEncryptedKey into json dictionary
jsonDictEncryptKey = json.loads(strEncryptedKey)

# then trying to decrypt the json key with Account.decrypt(), but this doesn't work?
decryptedKey = Account.decrypt(jsonDictEncryptKey, 'password')
```

I'm getting and error when trying to load the string encrypted key into json.loads(), but I'm also getting an error when just passing the string value to the decrypt() method. I'm not sure what format the keyfile_json parameter should be. I keep getting the following error when loading the strEncryptedKey to json:

```
jsonKey = json.loads(strEncryptedKey)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: change `str(Account.encrypt(acct_new.key, password = 'password'))` to `json.dumps(Account.encrypt(acct_new.key, password = 'password'))` will solve it. Using `str` to create json string is not gonna work.

Comment: thank you for responding. For future account keys, I'll try using the json.dumps instead, but for the ones that were already created using str(Account.encrypt()) and saved. Are there ways to work with these string keys to reload them and decrypt them?

Comment: `json.dumps(eval(strEncryptedKey))` would do the trick